# Visual Studio 17 C++ Link External Library (Boost Installation)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, build, visual-studio-2017

I installed external libraries and I can't seem to link them.

I right click on the the ​Project and hit Properties on the tool tip. I adjust the library directory to the library I want to use.

Project Property Pages > VC++ > Library Directories _ Add Directories - [ add the correct directory with [library_name].lib in it ]

Project Property Pages > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies - [ add [library_name].lib in list (w ';') ]

It builds alright, but then when I use an #include directive load the [my_include].hpp it says "cannot find source". But, why doesn't it just find the library? Why is it searching by source?

The build succeeds so long as it doesn't require code that requires the library. So, the dependency is met. What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to do source as well? I would rather just use the library.

add: How do you trace a build in Visual Studio C++. In Linux you can trace it all every step of the way if you want.

another add: In case you are wondering, there are build log file settings under

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> MSBuild ...

for inspection.

sandbox program

```
#include <iostream>
// squiggly under next line's include
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

Project -> Property Pages -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories _ set to _ C:\local\boost_1_68_0;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

where boost_1_68_0 is my installation of boost library.

No linking issues but I want to make sure the linking works too.

Comment: ***I try to load the [my_include].hpp*** What are you doing to load this file? A #include <> would return a completely different error.

Comment: Do I need the file if I have the library?

Comment: ***Do I need the file if I have the library?*** You will likely need the headers to compile whatever uses the library. If this is a .dll you also probably need the .lib (import library).

Comment: ***Do I need to do source as well?*** No.

Comment: You also need to add a path to the `c++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`.

Comment: I have ( Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories )

and

(Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Source Directories)

Does this thing search the subdirectories, or do I need to be specific with each one?

Comment: Neither of those. These are global settings. You most likely don't want that.

Comment: Found the one you were referring to. Are there any relevant tools? I will keep at it until it finds it.

Comment: I want to use (Linker -> Additional Library Directories) instead for the libraries I suppose.

Comment: Locating .hpp files have nothing at all to do with linking. Unless I am totally misunderstanding the question. I think you should edit your question and add a picture of the error window or prompt.

Comment: `C:\local\boost_1_68_0;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`  isn't there an include folder in the path. I expect the file `optional.hpp` to be in `C:\local\boost_1_68_0\include\boost\optional.hpp` meaning you should have added `C:\local\boost_1_68_0\include` to your include directories not `C:\local\boost_1_68_0`

Comment: There's no 'include' directory. It is 'path\boost_version\boost\optional\optional.hpp', but it is suppose to be just #include <boost/optional.hpp> in the program.

Comment: When I scan the debug log there's no mention of the file that I path'd to in Properties.

Comment: add: it is in both 'path\boost_version\boost\optional.hpp' and then in the 'path\boost_version\boost\optional\optional.h''.

Comment: Sorry then `path\boost_version` is correct. Make sure you changed the `Additional Include Directories` setting for all configurations. The settings are independent per configuration (debug, release ...) when you select you can select multiple configurations if you want.

Comment: I have stayed in debug the whole time and haven't touched release so I doubt that is the problem, but I will be sure. I think it might have to do with pch because it is now finding it on my target program. Did the exact same thing, works there but not there.

Comment: The only difference I can think of is I did a console with automatic pch (worthless junk) and didn't have pch with the other. I bet that's what's screwed up.

Comment: Thanks for your comments btw.

Answer (score 0):

Include files are a separate issue from library files Include files are textual source processed by the compiler, library files are binary data fed to the linker.

On the same project settings page as you added the library directory there is also a line for include paths, add the directory where the .h files for the code you want to use are found. Make sure the directory you specified for library search actually holds .lib files while the directory added for include paths holds .h (or .hpp or .hxx) files

If you get "unresolved external symbol" errors after the include files are found by the compiler you likely need to add actual library files (akin to #include directives but not exactly the same), with visual c++ this can be done with #pragma comment(lib, "") directives or by adding files to the Linker->Input->Additional dependencies line in the project settings.

Comment: I added to my post. I can't even get the 'include' working!